# Create, validate and compare data schema (for data harvest) in ckanr

Tags: r, schema, ckan, ropensci

This is a data harvest exercise. The code below ingests `data` as JSON. I would like to (a) print/extract the data schema from this `data` into `Schema1`. Then (b) compare it against some `Schema2`, because I need to change some metadata header names and accepted values.
Ckan has a Python "IDatasetform" plugin that I apparently allows this kind of analysis, but I don't know how to do this in R. Thanks

```
library(ckanr)
ckanr_setup(url = "https://energydata.info")
data <- ckanr:::package_show('6c0d331b-4dca-4815-a006-264745cbb9d0', as = 'json', pretty = TRUE)
data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(data)$result
## extract Schema1 from 'data'
## compare Schema1 vs. Schema2
```

Comment: `ckanr` maintainer here. need more information. what does it look like when using python? docs for this?

Comment: Thank you @sckott. I couldn't find a documentation of the process I want using python. But for starters, is there a way from ckanr to extract the data schema from any data dump (or by connecting to an API of a CKAN structure?).

As of now, what I had to do is dig up a dataset/package that has the most complete metadata; look at it as a json in a browser, copy paste it into R and remove the data values by hand (to end up with an empty template).

Comment: i'm not sure what a schema is, can you point to some examples?  it might be easier/more appropriate to open an issue in the repo as this isn't super simple https://github.com/ropensci/ckanr/issues